# Aligning an image on Outlook

Tags: html, outlook

I'm making an email newsletter and trying to make it look nice in Outlook.

One of the things I'm trying to achieve is to have images in the text that nicely line out to the left. The idea is that the text floats around the image, so a table wouldn't be possible, as then the text would be just on the right of the image.

After some googling, I found that in Outlook you still need to use the align HTML attribute.
This doesn't seem to work on the image though.

My code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<div style="width: 800px">
<img align="left" src="data:image/png;base64,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">
<p>This text should be aligned with the image</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque ea enim eveniet id illo itaque ratione reprehenderit. Consequatur explicabo facere natus nobis optio pariatur perspiciatis sint? Aliquid magni quae quaerat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet aperiam at corporis deserunt dolore, fugiat fugit illo illum laboriosam, libero mollitia nobis non quae reprehenderit sequi sit tenetur veniam voluptate. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi cum deserunt eaque error, ex ipsam itaque laboriosam molestias obcaecati optio quasi quis repellat soluta veritatis voluptatibus? Facilis odit ullam voluptate. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis cupiditate dolor fugit inventore ipsam odit pariatur perferendis voluptas voluptatum? At blanditiis culpa deleniti doloremque exercitationem itaque laboriosam nesciunt reiciendis voluptas. </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque ea enim eveniet id illo itaque ratione reprehenderit. Consequatur explicabo facere natus nobis optio pariatur perspiciatis sint? Aliquid magni quae quaerat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet aperiam at corporis deserunt dolore, fugiat fugit illo illum laboriosam, libero mollitia nobis non quae reprehenderit sequi sit tenetur veniam voluptate. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi cum deserunt eaque error, ex ipsam itaque laboriosam molestias obcaecati optio quasi quis repellat soluta veritatis voluptatibus? Facilis odit ullam voluptate. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis cupiditate dolor fugit inventore ipsam odit pariatur perferendis voluptas voluptatum? At blanditiis culpa deleniti doloremque exercitationem itaque laboriosam nesciunt reiciendis voluptas. </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why not use `float: left`?

Comment: Because outlook doesn't support floats.

Comment: but outlook can fall back to align which works in outlook.

Comment: well, above code doesn't seem to work. I still get the picture on top of the text, when importing the above code into outlook.

Comment: have you tired to use `align="left"` @Mark

Comment: @ScriptHost that is what I did, but it Outlook seems to ignore it.

Comment: can we try `margin-left` @Mark

Answer (score 0):

Try to with display: inline-block with table:

Reference: [Outlook template](https://codepen.io/jigneshdalvadi/pen/EmLQXb)

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="max-width: 800px; width: 100%">
  <tr>
    <td>
         <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="max-width: 180px; width: 100%; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;">
            <tr>
              <td>
                  <img src="data:image/png;base64,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">
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
           <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="max-width: 600px; width: 100%; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;">
            <tr>
              <td>
                  <p>This text should be aligned with the image</p>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque ea enim eveniet id illo itaque ratione reprehenderit. Consequatur explicabo facere natus nobis optio pariatur perspiciatis sint? Aliquid magni quae quaerat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet aperiam at corporis deserunt dolore, fugiat fugit illo illum laboriosam, libero mollitia nobis non quae reprehenderit sequi sit tenetur veniam voluptate. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi cum deserunt eaque error, ex ipsam itaque laboriosam molestias obcaecati optio quasi quis repellat soluta veritatis voluptatibus? Facilis odit ullam voluptate. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis cupiditate dolor fugit inventore ipsam odit pariatur perferendis voluptas voluptatum? At blanditiis culpa deleniti doloremque exercitationem itaque laboriosam nesciunt reiciendis voluptas. </p>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque ea enim eveniet id illo itaque ratione reprehenderit. Consequatur explicabo facere natus nobis optio pariatur perspiciatis sint? Aliquid magni quae quaerat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet aperiam at corporis deserunt dolore, fugiat fugit illo illum laboriosam, libero mollitia nobis non quae reprehenderit sequi sit tenetur veniam voluptate. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi cum deserunt eaque error, ex ipsam itaque laboriosam molestias obcaecati optio quasi quis repellat soluta veritatis voluptatibus? Facilis odit ullam voluptate. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis cupiditate dolor fugit inventore ipsam odit pariatur perferendis voluptas voluptatum? At blanditiis culpa deleniti doloremque exercitationem itaque laboriosam nesciunt reiciendis voluptas. </p>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This does work, but doesn't give the effect I'm after. Now the text doesn't flow around the picture. The text and image are in their own column.